# How can I start multiple programs simultaneously?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I have 4 programs that I'd like to start by using only 1 script or shortcut. How can I achieve this? Is Powershell able to do that? I tried to do it using a .bat file but the script pauses until the program is stopped...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can start multiple applications in a batch file without pausing using start:

> start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\" iexplore.exe
>   start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla FireFox\" firefox.exe

The above in a batch file will start both IE and FireFox together.

The /d indicates the working folder for the command and the last part is the command name.

If you specifically want to use Powershell you will need to call the System.Diagnostics library in .Net to launch the external process as follows:

> [Diagnostics.Process]::Start('yourapplication','arguments')